# ¿Cómo hacer un while que se repita máximo 5 veces en php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, while, tablas

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

En esta consulta llamo a la tabla "reparación", y le digo que me de los valores que sean iguales a otros datos que vienen de un formulario anterior:

```
$sqldesmo="select reparacion.* from reparacion
 where nro_cliente='$cliente' and fecha='$fech'";
$okdesmo=mysqli_query($sqldesmo,$con);

<table border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='1'><strong>CODIGOS DE REPARACIONES</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php
while(($producto=mysqli_fetch_assoc($okdesmo))>0)
{

    ?>
<tr>
<td style='color:#000;'><b><?php echo  $producto['nro_reparacion']; ?></b></td>
</tr>   

     <?php  } ?>
</table>
```

El problema es que esta consulta me genera en una tabla todos los datos al tiempo ejemplo de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi while se repita máximo 5 veces?, el while tendría que imprimir la misma tabla máximo 5 veces, pero con cada dato encontrado. Este es un ejemplo de como debería quedar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo aplico a un PDF entonces la idea es que el while imprima máximo 5 registros por pagina de PDF, si tenemos más de 5 registros en una página los demás debería imprimirlos en otra.

Me confirman si la pregunta quedo más entendible :)

Quedo atento a cualquier ayuda muchas gracias, mil bendiciones.

Comment: O sea el while estaria por afuera de la cuenta? agrega como te vienen los datos.. ahora esta un poco mas claro tu problema..

Comment: Y no te sería más fácil hacer la consulta limitada a 5 elementos e iterar con un foreach todo el resultado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
$productos    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($okdesmo);
$totalPaginas = count($productos) / 5;
if (count($productos) % 5 != 0) {
    $totalPaginas = $totalPaginas + 1;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $totalPaginas; $i++) {
    echo "inicias la página";
    $subProductos = array_splice($productos, 0, 5 < count($productos) ? 5 : count($productos));
    foreach ($subProductos as $producto) {
        echo "<table border='1'><tr><td colspan='1'><strong>CODIGOS DE REPARACIONES</strong></td></tr><tr>";
        echo "<td style='color:#000;'><b>";
        echo $producto['nro_reparacion'];
        echo '</b></td>
            </tr>
            </table>';
    }
    echo "finaliza la página";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Donde dice inicias página lo debes reemplazar por todos los pasos para crear una página de tu pdf y en finaliza página debes hacer el salto de página.